# how could I find the recurrence of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, time-complexity, recurrence

Consider the following recursive algorithm, where n is a positive integer. Find the recurrence, as a function of n, which represents how many asterisks will be printed when `Asterisk(n)` is called.

```
Asterisk (n): 
   if n > 0: 
      for ( i=0; i<n; i=i+2):
         print (*)
         Asterisk (n-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `A(n)` is number of asterisks printed for `n`

From the `for` loop you can see that for every `n` you are printing `ceil(n/2)` asterisks because the loop increments by `2`. And also for every asterisk printed there are extra `A(n-2)` asterisks.

So the recurrence would be

```
A(n) = 0 if n <= 0
     = (ceil(n/2))( 1 + A(n-2) ) if n > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of `*` is:

```
1, 4, 15, 64, 325, ...
```

The recurrence formula for this is

```
f(1) = 1
f(n) = n * f(n-1) + n
```

In your case, `Asterisk` will generate this sequence, but in a different pattern:

```
1, 1, 4, 4, 15, 15, 64, 64, 325, 325, ...
```

Basically, every value appears twice, so the 2*i-th value corresponds to the i-th original value.

```
Asterisk(n) = 0                                    if n < 1
Asterisk(n) = Asterisk(n + 1)                      if n is odd
Asterisk(n) = (n/2) * Asterisk(n-2) + (n/2)        if n is even
```

Programmatically speaking:

```
int Asterisk(int n){
    if(n < 1) return 0;
    if(n % 2 == 1) return mAst(n + 1);
    return (n/2) * mAst(n-2) + (n/2);
}
```